# Equivelance between two different dynamic promise provider chains

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am wondering if the two code blocks are basically equivalent:

```
const executePromises = function(listOfProviders){

    let p = Promise.resolve(null);

    for(let i = 0; i < listOfProviders.length; i++){
       p = p.then(v => listOfProviders[i]());
    }

   return p;

};
```

I believe the above is basically equivalent to:

```
const executePromises = async function(listOfProviders) {

    for(let i = 0; i < listOfProviders.length; i++){
       await listOfProviders[i]();
    }

};
```

does anyone see a discrepancy?

Comment: In the first you will return a promise that resolves to the last `listofProviders` function call result. In the second you await all the `listofProviders` promises but do nothing with the result. So, no, they're not the same.

Comment: Also `p` is a `const`. You can't reassign to it.

Comment: actually, (once it's changed to `let` rather than `const` of course) the promise returned by `executePromises` is the promise returned by the last call to `listOfProviders[i]()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance in the first function (assuming the const is fixed) the function returns `p` which is the last promise from the chain.

Comment: to make the second code the same ... add `let p` before the loop, then `p = await listOfProviders[i]();`, and finally, `return p` after the loop

Comment: or to make the first code work like the second, simply omit the `return p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. They are not the same**. Even if you return the promise as someone pointed out in comments.

**Difference:**

- When using `async await` with `for-loop`, it should be remembered that for loop goes to next iteration only when the awaited promise has been resolved in the current iteration.
- On the other hand, when `.then` is used in a `for-loop`, that `for-loop` doesn't wait for the promise to resolve before going to the next iteration.

I have tweaked your code to demonstrate this. Observe that **Line** **A** is being called at different point of time in each code snippet.

`Async await` inside `for-loop` code:

```js
function createPromiseWhichResolveAfterOneSec(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("About to resolve promise with value:",i);//Line A
            resolve(i);
        },1000)
    })
}

const executePromises = async function(listOfProviders) {

    let p;
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < listOfProviders.length; i++){
        console.log("before", i);
        p = await createPromiseWhichResolveAfterOneSec(i);
        console.log("after", i);
    }
    console.log(i);
    return p;

};


let listOfProviders = [1,2,3,4,5];
let promise = executePromises(listOfProviders);
promise.then(value => console.log("this is the final value of promise chain:",value)).catch(()=>{});
```

**With `then` in `for-loop`:**

```js
function createPromiseWhichResolveAfterOneSec(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("About to resolve promise with value:",i);//Line A
            resolve(i);
        },1000)
    })
}


const executePromises = function(listOfProviders){

    let p = Promise.resolve(null);

    for(let i = 0; i < listOfProviders.length; i++){
        console.log("before", i);
        p = p.then(v => createPromiseWhichResolveAfterOneSec(i));
        console.log("after", i);
    }

    return p;

};

let listOfProviders = [1,2,3,4,5];
let promise = executePromises(listOfProviders);
promise.then(value => console.log("this is the final value of promise chain:",value)).catch(()=>{});
```